# How to paginate a list a files in a directory in asp?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

We're using `folder = objFSO.GetFolder(<path>)` to get a list of files with a directory.

We then `For Each` over the `folder.Files` array to output the list of filenames.

We've got to a point where there are thousands of files in the folder and its quite slow so we want to add some pagination to the screen. So to all show 500 files at a time. I have no idea if this is even possible and all Google searches haven't helped.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you using the FSO object on the client side or the server side?

Comment: Sorry, this is server-side scripting.

Comment: Just a side note: Do you really need to page through thousands of items? Wouldn't it be better to filter for a result set of max. 100 items?

Comment: VBScript is quite limited.. writing small ASP.NET page that will do that is trivial, then you can "consume" it with classic ASP. Does your web server also have support for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, regarding the listing of the files, can you get the listing and persist (cache) the result somewhere to speed up repeated access? This is a method we use in .NET when getting large listings of files (we're using ASP.NET Web Pages so we just use WebCache.Set, but I imagine you could write it to a text file if you needed to).

I see some anecdotal evidence [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/vb6-filesystemobject-makes-it-easier-to-work-with-files/1050078) that FSO is quite slow when listing large numbers of files:

> One consideration not addressed is speed. I had a small VB app which used FileSystemObject to loop through files in a folder. It took approx. 5-7 minutes just to walk through every file in a given folder (approx. 2200 files). When I switched to using the DIR() command, I could walk the files in about 6-10 seconds. There are limitations to DIR() as well, but the speed factor was a huge consideration which went against FileSystemObject.

Obviously once you have the listing you would loop through them 500 at a time with an offset / page size

EDIT: I include an example on how to use WScript.Shell to do this from a couple of aspfaq.com articles I found ([1](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html) | [2](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-ping-command-from-asp-and-retrieve-the-results.html))

```
Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set objCmd = objWShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /C dir c:\") 
strPResult = objCmd.StdOut.Readall()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Chaching the data isn't an option and the directory is constantly have files added and removed. Do you have any other ideas? I seems my fears may be true.

Comment: Hi Ash, not a problem. Then I think WScript.Shell would be your next best option. I've included a sample above, does that help and are you able to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an online file browser a few years ago (available [here](http://www.daleanderson.ca/edb)), and found that it was reading the file sizes that slowed down file listing with FSO. As soon as I skipped that, then listing went lightning fast.

For pagination, I would recommend creating a 'disconnected' ado recordset out of the file names, and then use that for the actual navigation of names... then you've got pagination built in... as well as sorting and searching.  Let me know if you're interested in a code example.

Comment: Could you post some code that generates a list without reading the file size?

Comment: Actually, it was the subfolder size that caused the real slowdown... been a while since i've touched this stuff.